# What's the right way in Java 8 to evaluate if /path/a is a subdirectory of /path?

Tags: java, java-8, stream, subdirectory

Pretty much what the title asks.

Say I'm passed a Path of "/tmp/foo/bar" and I want to specifically ensure that that path is a subdirectory of a path "/tmp", what is the most "Java 8"ish way of going about this?

Specifically I am interested in asking "Given two independent paths, /foo and /foo/bar/baz how can I test if /foo/bar/baz is a subdirectory of /foo without recursing the directory tree?" I am not interested in exploring all the sub directories under /foo and finding /foo/bar/baz downstream.

I've been playing with the idea of

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final Path root = Paths.get("/tmp");
    final Path path0 = Paths.get("/");
    final Path path1 = Paths.get("/opt/location/sub");
    final Path path2 = Paths.get("/tmp/location/sub");

    final Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z].*$");

    final Function<Path, String> f = p -> root.relativize(p).toString();

    Assert.assertFalse("root",ptrn.matcher(f.apply(root)).matches());
    Assert.assertFalse("path0",ptrn.matcher(f.apply(path0)).matches());
    Assert.assertFalse("path1",ptrn.matcher(f.apply(path1)).matches());
    Assert.assertTrue("path2",ptrn.matcher(f.apply(path2)).matches());
}
```

but this feels like I worked right up to the edge of Java 8 and then dove back to old patterns and missed the boat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> boolean startsWith(Path other)
> ```
>
> Tests if this path starts with the given path.

Answer (score 0):

## For getting meaningful assert messages

### *with AssertJ (JUnits 3,4,5+...)*

tl;dr

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

    ...
    assertThat(path2 + "").startsWith("/tmp/"));
```

### *with vanilla JUnit 4*

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;        // !DEPRECATED! see: https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)
import static org.hamcrest.core.StringStartsWith;

    assertThat(path2 + "", startsWith("/tmp/"))
```

NOTE: Harmcrest's assertThat is removed from JUnit 5. So, in 2020, a more common practice was to use AssertJ, which is easier for future upgrades: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core

---

**Details:**  The Unit Test problem with `Path#startsWith` is that it returns boolean. So a failed test would return a silly reason:

> *"Expected TRUE, but was FALSE"*

So, for a better Unit Tests maintenance / code improvements, a better way would be using an assertion framework. That speeds-up your troubleshooting, by messaging like this, out-of-the-box:

> *"Expecting: **<"/opt/location/sub">** to start with: <"/tmp/foo">."*

**Note:** Although AssertJ has Path friendly methods, like `isDirectory`, `startsWith(::Path)`, depending on the environment, they could lead to `failed to resolve actual real path` messages. So it's more stable converting the `Path` to `String` before asserting: --either by `path2.toString()` --or by `path2 + ""`.